# How to estimate a best fitting line that separates variables on a scatterplot by some third binary outcome variable with 95% accuracy?

Tags: classification, r, regression, svm

0

I've been thinking about this and haven't found a non-brute force method of doing it. I have a series of scatterplots depicting the relationship between two predictor variables and a third binary outcome variable. The relationship is obvious simply looking at the scatterplots, so I want to find a way to extract an equation that I can graph on top of the scatterplot depicting this relationship. Specifically, though, I want to create a line that separates the data in such a way that the accuracy of the data above the line is about 95%. In other words, I want to be able to say that if you are above the line, you are 95% likely to be in the specified condition (0 in the example below). To be clear, I know how to add a line to the scatterplot, I just don't know how to get the specific parameter estimates for the line that achieves this accuracy. I've created a reproducible example below as an example:

```
# Generate data 
x <- runif(10000,400,600)
y <- runif(10000,0,1)
temp <- cbind.data.frame(x,y)
temp$z <- 0
# Create the split
for (i in 1:10000){if (1.5-0.0025*temp$x[i]-temp$y[i]>0){temp$z[i]=1}}

# create some randomness
for (i in 1:10000){
  dist=(y[i]-(1.5-0.0025*x[i]))^2
  if (dist<.005)
  {if (abs(dist)*abs(rnorm(1,0,.05))<.000005)
    {temp$z[i]=abs(temp$z[i]-1)}
  }
}

# plot
ggplot(temp, aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(z)))+geom_point(size=.25)
```

I've had a few friends suggest support vector machines, which do a great job of separating the data, but work too well - they aim for peak accuracy and achieve 97% accuracy, rather than aiming for a predetermined accuracy, in my case 95%. Is there a way to change the optimization method to focus on 95% accuracy instead? Or is there some other way of achieving this?

Thanks all!